# Infinitive.. How to form these sentences correctly?

Tags: infinitives, formality, to-infinitive, infinitive-clauses

> 1) I intended to have spent my summer vacation in the country
>   2) I knew him to be waiting for me that evening -
>       I would rather say "I knew he was waiting for me that evening)
>
> 3) We are to meet at the station at six oclock
>   4) He is known to have been doing a lot to improve his knowledge of English
>   5) To read is useful - I would rather say "reading is beautiful"
>   6) I saw him enter the room - I would rather say "I saw him entering the room"
>   7) I felt him to be an honest man
>   8) Have you ever heard him complain of difficulty?

So, I have taken these sentences from a grammar book. However, some of them sound weird to me. My question is are these sentences too formal? How come I have never come across this kind of grammar usage.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. As this is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum, it is usually better to ask one question at a time, explaining why you are confused about a certain point of grammar or usage. For what it's worth, all of these sentences are grammatically correct, but not everyone would use them in conversation.

Answer (score -1):

Some of your answers are wrong, and also some examples provided by the book are also wrong.

Here is how I'd rewrite the wrong ones:

*He is known for having been doing a lot to improve his knowledge of English*

*To read/Reading is useful* (Beautiful is absolutely different from useful)

*I saw him enter the room/entering* (Both mean the same thing)

*I considered him to be an honest man*.

Comment: None of the examples are "wrong," in the absence of other context, but it is true they are not necessarily idiomatic, especially in conversational English.